# Run Spring web application without installing tomcat on system

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am creating simple spring web application without any database, using excel sheets to save data. I will be using tomcat or any other webserver. 
Once application is completed, I will be giving this application to a non-technical person. So wanted to know any thoughts on below points :
1) Shall I use tomcat or any other web server in this case.
2) Is it possible for someone to use my application without actually installing tomcat in his system ?

Please help.

Comment: use spring boot with embedded tomcat.

Comment: @shi : using spring boot, anybody would be able to run my application without installing /deploying in any webserver ? and how they will use, Will i need to give war file ?

Comment: you just need to give them the jar file and they will be able to run it using simple java -jar commaand

Comment: @shi : Thanks shi for your advice. In this case they just would need the java installed on their system, right ? And which web server should I use for my spring application, consider it as a lightweight application ?

Comment: yes, they need to have java installed on their system. you could use embedded tomcat or jetty. I prefer tomcat.

Comment: @shi : Can we embed any database like mysql as well in spring boot.

Comment: you can embed h2.